# Solving $\frac{18^{4n}\times 2^{3(n^2-6n)}\times 3^{2(1-4n)}}{12^2} =2$ for $n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Saw a indices question in my my maths textbook which proved to be quite bothersome. For reference, I'm in Grade 10 hence it may be rather easy for some of you :).

> Given that
> $$ M = \frac{18^{4n}\times 2^{3(n^2-6n)}\times 3^{2(1-4n)}}{12^2}        $$
> Find the values of $n$ for which $M=2$.

Edit:

I'm not sure how to approach the powers. I substituted 2 in for M and hence made the LHS equal to 288, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: can you include your attempt or describe what is stopping you from completing the task?

Comment: I'm not sure how to approach the powers. I substituted 2 in for M and hence made the LHS equal to 288, but I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: ??? If you substitute $2$ for $M$ the LHS becomes $2$, not $282$...

Answer (score 1):

Guide:

Alright, you have obtained

$$2 \times 12^2 = 18^{4n} \times 2^{3(n^2-6n)} \times 3^{3^{2(1-4n)}}$$

Notice that $12 = 2^2 \times 3$ and $18=2 \times 3^2$.

$$2\times 2^4 \times 3^2 = (2 \times 3^2)^{4n} \times 2^{3(n^2-6n)} \times 3^{2(1-4n)}$$

Now try to group them according to power of $2$ and power of $3$ and compare their indices. Give it a try.